# Cannot find module "./src/index.js"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, reactjs-flux, webpack-dev-server

I am new to React and Flux and cannot figure out how to fix the error below. After loading `localhost:8080/app`, the console is showing `cannot find module "./src/index.js"`
(see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avyb7.png) for a screenshot of the errror).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code? This is in my Webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:[
    "./src/index.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "get and display user github info",
  "main": "react.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "krishna",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies":{
    "babel-core": "5.8.*",
    "babel-loader": "5.3.*",
    "webpack": "1.12.*",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react":"^0.14.7",
    "react-dom":"^0.14.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the obvious question. but does this file exists: `your_webpack_folder/src/index.js` ? If yes, maybe webpack found some error while processing this file and didn't included it.

Comment: yes the webpack folder exist. the above is code is my webpack to run it.

Comment: what is your folder structure?

Comment: Try giving the absolute path.